# Prevent certain node groups from being included in the Add menu

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, animation-nodes, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I have created many node groups, and want some to appear in the *Add > Group* menu, but not all of them.

How do I hide certain groups from appearing in that menu?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Simply set the name of the group to start with a period.

Make sure you're setting the name of the group (what appears in the menu), and not the name or label of the instance of the group.

[image]

Comment: love these little quirks in Blender :))

Comment: And it works for other data-blocks, too (Materials, Scenes, etc.)

Comment: Great find, wasn't aware of this. Though I never really needed this it is a very welcome feature. Useful if you want to create very complex node assets with many sub node components and don't want certain "working parts" to pollute the top level add menu.

Comment: Just remember that hidden nodegroups also won't show in the Nodegroup node dropdown. So if you want to add hidden nodegroups to some nodetree, you need to do it with Python.

Comment: It's a useful feature, though I was looking all over the group settings for a toggle or something. There's no way to find this without google.

Comment: Wow. Learn something every day.

Answer (score 1):

**Additional help:**

Hiding node groups works by adding a period at start, for example:

```
myGroup == .myGroup
```

Hidden node groups are now invisible in all menus. But if you like to add them to a new node tree, just open the outliner in the "*Blender File*" filter mode.

All nodegroups, even the hidden ones, are listed there. You can drag and drop them into your tree now.

**Example:**

[image]